# Erratic behaviour when mixing pandas, datetime and numpy timedelta (bug?)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have noticed by chance that some operations (a > b) on datetime that should give the same (well-defined) results actually give different results (some correct, some wrong, some just throwing an error) depending on whether I do them on a pandas dataframe or in numpy. I try to give a small example below. For brevity, I use dateutile.parser.parse function, but I think that the issue comes up in the interplay between datetime, pandas and numpy packages, in particular when using pandas' DatetimeIndex.

First I try to create a df out of np.timedelta64, and that I can't compare to a single np.timedelta64; it's a clean error, which I think is ok:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse
a1 = np.array([np.datetime64(parse('20200101')),np.datetime64(parse('20150101'))]).reshape((1,-1))
a2 = np.array([np.datetime64(parse('20100101')),np.datetime64(parse('20180101'))]).reshape((-1,1))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a1-a2)
df1 > np.timedelta64(1000,'D')
```

With the above df1 is:

```
    0                       1
0   3652 days 00:00:00  1826 days 00:00:00
1   730 days 00:00:00   -1096 days +00:00:00
```

and the second command throws an error "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''". So far, so good.

However, if I write:

```
a3 = pd.DatetimeIndex(a1.flatten()).values.reshape((1,-1))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(a3 - a2)
```

then the result looks similar: df2 =

```
    0           1
0   3652 days   1826 days
1   730 days    -1096 days
```

But in this case, `df2 > np.timedelta64(1000,'D')` not only does not throw an error, but it gives a wrong answer:

```
    0       1
0   True    True
1   True    False
```

On the other hand, if instead of doing `pd.DataFrame(a3-a2) > np.timedelta64(1000,'D')`, we do `pd.DataFrame(a3-a2 > np.timedelta64(1000,'D'))`, we get the good answer:

```
    0       1
0   True    True
1   False   False
```

Given the situation, I imagine there must be a bug somewhere, although I am not quite sure where. Maybe I am just misunderstanding some notations, but the behavior is a bit puzzling anyway. Some issue may come from the fact that, with the above definitions, some dtypes (e.g. df1) are in microseconds, some other (e.g. df2) are in nanoseconds; however, I expect these should be treated correctly, since the output is correctly transformed to days...

For reference, I am using Python 3.5, numpy version 1.12.1, pandas version 0.18.0, and python-dateutil version 2.5.1.

EDIT: After further testing, and taking into account Paul's answer below:

- The error has apparently been solved with Pandas version 0.19.2. Paul's code snippet below, as well as the code above concerning df2, have been tested by Paul to correctly work under Linux, Python3.5, Pandas 0.19.2, and I have also checked them under both Linux and windows, both Python2.7 and Python3.5, Pandas 0.20.2.
- In 0.18.2, Paul's code snippet below gives the same (wrong) answer as df2 above.
- However, in my tests, also in 0.20.2, the first code above (df1 on this question) gives a wrong answer, giving all False. This is probably due to the fact that pandas stores the dates as microseconds (because Paul's explicit cast solves the issue), while numpy as nanoseconds, so there is a silent factor of 1000. Still, I would think that this should be taken care of automatically...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example on Linux with Python 3.6 and pandas version 0.19.2, numpy version 1.12.0. I get the correct value for the comparison. If you open a clean shell and paste what you have here exactly, do you actually get the answers you've specified? If so, maybe try updating pandas?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! That example was from a windows machine (that I can't easily update). Now I'm on another windows machine, with Python2.7 and pandas version 0.20.2, and indeed the comparison with df2 works fine, but very unexpectedly now the comparison with df1 does not throw an error and instead gives a wrong result! This time all 4 comparisons return "False"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is apparently not consistent, as I am not able to recreate your problem on the latest version of `pandas`, but it does seem that the main difference between the two situations is that `df1` is storing `np.dtype('timedelta64[us]')` objects and `df2` is storing `np.dtype('timedelta64[ns]')` objects.

I'm not sure why you think that `df1 > np.timedelta64(1000, 'D')` should fail - my intuition would be that it does not have any type-casting problems. That said, it seems that, as of at least version `0.19.2`, if you always make sure to cast your dataframes to `np.timedelta64[ns]`, you won't have this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

a1 = np.array([np.datetime64(datetime(2020, 1, 1)),
               np.datetime64(datetime(2015, 1, 1))]).reshape((1,-1))
a2 = np.array([np.datetime64(datetime(2010,1,1)),
               np.datetime64(datetime(2018,1,1))]).reshape((-1,1))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a1 - a2).astype(np.dtype('timedelta64[ns]'))
kiloday = np.timedelta64(1000, 'D')

df1 > kiloday
#        0      1
# 0   True   True
# 1  False  False
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks again for your detailed answer! I have tried your snippet in 0.20.2 and it works (and in 0.18.2 it does not throw an error but it gives the wrong answer). I was not claiming that throwing an error was "good", just that it was better than happily giving a wrong answer... Anyway, without the explicit cast (as in my original df1), this still seems to give a wrong answer in new pandas versions, as in edited question; don't you think that this would be an unexpected behavior? Just asking in order to understand whether I should report this to pandas devs... thanks again!

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci Definitely the wrong answer, but it may be that pandas has imperfect `np.timedelta64` support. Hopefully this `us`/`ns` difference helps narrow down exactly where the code is going wrong.